# Array first element

Tags: arrays, powershell, import-csv

I am trying to split an array read off a csv file and I cannot capture anything but the first array element. Here is my code

```
$EmployeeLists = @()
$ManagerLists = @()

$CSVFiles = Import-CSV "C:\T2\SetManagers\EmployeeManager.csv"

ForEach($CSVFile in $CSVFiles) { $EmployeeLists += ($CSVFile.Employee) }
ForEach($CSVFile in $CSVFiles) { $ManagerLists += ($CSVFile.Manager) }

ForEach($EmployeeList in $EmployeeLists) { $EmployeeLists.Split(",")[0] | Out-File "C:\T2\SetManagers\ESplit.txt" -Append }
ForEach($ManagerList in $ManagerLists) { $ManagerLists.Split(",")[0] | Out-File "C:\T2\SetManagers\MSplit.txt" -Append }
```

My put put looks like this

```
Smith
Smith
Smith
Smith
Smith
Smith
Smith
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper formatting goes a long way:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path C:\T2\SetManagers\EmployeeManager.csv

foreach ($list in $csv) {
    $list.Employee.Split(',')[0] | Out-File -Path C:\T2\SetManagers\ESplit.txt -Append
    $list.Manager.Split(',')[0] | Out-File -Path C:\T2\SetManagers\MSplit.txt -Append
}
```

Your problem was referring to the overall list instead of a single element in your `foreach` loops.

Answer (score 3):

[Maximilian Burszley's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51368095/45375) explains the problem with your code and offers an effective solution.

- If you're happy with your (fixed) code's performance and you see no need to *improve* your code, that's all you need.
- To learn about reusable techniques that both shorten and speed up your code, read on.

---

**A concise, PowerShell-idiomatic solution that performs much better** (PSv4+):

```sh
# Read the CSV rows (into custom objects whose properties contain the
# column values).
$rows = Import-CSV "C:\T2\SetManagers\EmployeeManager.csv"

# Collect all Employee and Manager column values in an array each.
$employeeLists = $rows.Employee
$managerLists = $rows.Manager

# Loop over all column values, extract only the first ","-separated token each
# and send the combined output to an output file.
$employeeLists.ForEach({ ($_ -split ',')[0] }) > "C:\T2\SetManagers\ESplit.txt"
$managerLists.ForEach({ ($_ -split ',')[0] }) >  "C:\T2\SetManagers\MSplit.txt"
```

Specifically, the code above *avoids*:

- Building up an array in a *loop* with `+=`, which necessitates *recreating* the array (with the new value appended) in *each iteration*.

  - Instead, it uses [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) (PSv3+) to directly retrieve an array of property values (e.g., `$employeeLists = $rows.Employee`)
  - Even in PSv2 a relatively concise and more efficient form is possible; the PSv2 equivalent of `$employeeLists = $rows.Employee` is:

    ```sh
        # *PowerShell* does the work of collecting the outputs from the individual
        # loop iterations and simply returns an array.
        $employeeLists = foreach ($row in $rows) { $row.Employee }
    ```
  - Finally, if you do need to build up a collection iteratively and speed matters, use
    an *extensible* collection type such as `[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]` and its `.Add()` method instead of arrays with `+=`.
- Calling `Out-File` in a *loop*, which incurs the cmdlet's startup and teardown cost in each iteration and also requires reopening and closing the file every time.

  - Instead, the *combined* output of the statement is written to the output file in a *single* `Out-File` call (shortened to `>` for brevity).
- The PSv4+ `.ForEach()` *method* rather than a `foreach` *loop* performs better (though only slightly), and has the advantage that you can directly use it as the first segment of a pipeline (whereas a `foreach` loop would require wrapping in `$(...)`).
  In PSv3-, use a `foreach` loop.